# Is it possible to know when a particular panorama item is displayed

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I have a list of panorama Items.

I want to know when the user has reached a particular panorama item and then take necessary action.

I tried using the eventhandler GotFocus on the panorama item but it doesn't get invoked when the user reaches the item

Comment: Can I do this using gesture listener? I can find when the user has flicked and in which direction to figure out the panorama item the user is currently on

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Panorama control has a [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectionchanged%28VS.92%29.aspx) event which is fired when the user pans from one item to the next. You can then use the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex properties to find the item which is currently in view.

Comment: Is it also possible to find out FlowDirection of Panorama ? if possible than how to find out the flow direction of panorama item.Thank you